# Como pegar o valor de um state e enviar para outa pagina usando React-native?

Tags: react-native

Bom dia, acabei de criar componente separado que é um picker select, sua função é pegar os  valores inseridos no banco de dados e mostrar para o usuário selecionar, aqui está meu codigo.

```
import React, {Component}from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Picker } from '@react-native-picker/picker';
import firebase from '../../services/firebaseConection';

export default class PickerCadastroAdm extends Component{
    
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          setor:[],
          setor_selecionado: ""
        };

        firebase.database().ref('setores').once('value', (snapshot)=>{
              let state = this.state;
              state.setor =[];
    
              snapshot.forEach((childItem)=>{
                  state.setor.push({
                  key: childItem.key,
                  setor:childItem.val().nome
                });
              });
              this.setState(state);
            });
        }
        

    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.PickerView}>
                <Picker
                    selectedValue={this.state.setor_selecionado}
                    style={styles.picker}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                        this.setState({ setor_selecionado: itemValue})
                    }
                >
                    {this.state.setor.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                            <Picker.Item
                                label={item.setor}
                                value={item.setor}
                                key={index}
                            />
                        );
                    })}
                </Picker>
    </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    PickerView:{
        marginTop: 5,
        backgroundColor: '#ccc',
        alignItems:'center',
        width: '90%',
        borderRadius: 7
    },
    picker:{
        width: '100%'
    }
});
```

Estou usando este componente dentro de uma função que fica em outa página:

```
export default function cadastroAdm(){
     const [nome, setNome] = useState('');
     const [setor, setSetor] = useState('');
    
     <View>
       <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Nome completo"
          autoCorrect={false}
          onChangeText={(nome)=> setNome(nome)}
          value={nome}
        />

         <PickerCadastroAdm/>
     </View>
}
```

Preciso pegar o valor que foi selecionado e passar onde estou chamando o componente, como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar as propriedades do componente para passar o valor selecionado e a função que atualiza este valor.

1. Remova do construtor o estado `setor_selecionado`.

```
// PickerCadastroAdm.js

constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    setor:[]
  };
  // Restante do código
}
```

2. Atualize as props do componente `Picker` localizado na função`render`.

```
  <Picker
    selectedValue={this.props.setor}
    style={styles.picker}
    onValueChange={(itemValue) => this.props.setSetor(itemValue)}
  >
```

3. Agora passe o estado do componente `CadastroAdm` para as props do componente `PickerCadastroAdm`.

```
// CadastroAdm.js

<PickerCadastroAdm
  setor={setor}
  setSetor={setSetor}
/>
```

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, funcionou certinho. Deus abençoe vc!